# Speeding up R code to match rows between two data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, join, match, inner-join

I need help running this code faster. I am trying to pull the rows of "stuff" that correspond to the entries in "data". I have 800,000 rows in stuff and 17,000 rows in data. It has take 24+ hours and still not finished. I am new to coding and don't know of any other way to try this

Here is the code i am running

```
plays <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=16218, ncol=7))

for(i in 1:nrow(data)){
  for(j in 1:nrow(stuff)){
    if(stuff[j,4] == data[i,5] & stuff[j,2] == data[i,2]){
      plays[i,] <- stuff[j,]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: do something called inner join ie `dplyr::inner_join(data, stuff, by = ....)`

Answer (score 1):

As [Onyambu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8380272/onyambu) said, using `dplyr::innerjoin` is going to be faster than nested for loops, and the code is simpler too.

Here's an example:

```
library(tibble)

# Create 'stuff' tibble
stuff <- tibble(
  ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
  Name = c("Apple", "Banana", "Orange", "Grape"),
  Color = c("Red", "Yellow", "Orange", "Green")
)

# Create 'data' tibble
data <- tibble(
  ID = c(2, 4, 5),
  Value = c(10, 20, 30),
  Weight = c(0.5, 0.8, 1.2)
)

inner_join(stuff, data, by = "ID")

# A tibble: 2 × 5
     ID Name   Color  Value Weight
  <dbl> <chr>  <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1     2 Banana Yellow    10    0.5
2     4 Grape  Green     20    0.8
```

If you're still experiencing slowdown, I would consider using a different library. [Here is a comparison of some different libraries, and their performance on joins.](https://h2oai.github.io/db-benchmark/)